# codility counting lesson 2 : swap elements from arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I'm studying Codility Counting Lesson (https://codility.com/media/train/2-CountingElements.pdf) and I need help to understand the fastest solution.

I would like to know what does counting function means:

```
count = counting(A, m)
```

**The Problem:**

You are given an integer m (1 < m < 1000000) and two non-empty, zero-indexed arrays A and B of n integers, a0, a1, ... ,  an−1 and b0, b1, ... , bn−1 respectively (0 < ai, bi < m). The goal is to check whether there is a swap operation which can be performed on these arrays in such a way that the sum of elements in array A equals the sum of elements in array B after the swap. By swap operation we mean picking one element from array A and one element from array B and exchanging them.
The solution:

```
def fast_solution(A, B, m):
    n = len(A)
    sum_a = sum(A)
    sum_b = sum(B)
    d = sum_b - sum_a
    if d % 2 == 1:
        return False
    d //= 2
    count = counting(A, m)
    for i in xrange(n):
        if 0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m and count[B[i] - d] > 0:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: `counting` is not a built-in function in Python, that must be from them. Could you provide the source of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting is defined earlier in the text and is implemented as follows:

```
def counting(A, m):
    n = len(A)
    count = [0] * (m + 1)
    for k in xrange(n):
        count[A[k]] += 1
    return count
```

It just counts how many times each element appears in the array.

Comment: ohh, You are right. I was not seeing that. :)

Very useful you answer.

Thanks!